# graphql-java and hibernate - lazy loads relations that are not even specified in query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I hope someone have experienced something similar and can help me:

I am using graphql-java (and spring, graphql-java-tools etc.) and hibernate and I am experiencing a weird issue:

Whenever i execute a query (or mutation) and load an entity via Hibernate, it automatically lazy loads the relations. I can see this when looking in Hibernates query log.

This happens even though i dont load the field in the query, and even also when i delete the field from the schema altogether.

Example, given the following schema:

```
query {
    getAllItems: [Item!]!
}

Item {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    owner: Person!
}
Person {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    items: [Item!]!
}
```

And a Hibernate entity (pseudo code):

```
@Entity
class Item {
    @Id
    private String id

    @Column
    private String name

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private: Person
    ...
}
```

The following query:

```
getAllItems {
    id
    name
}
```

And a hibernate query that loads just the items, would end up with first fetching all the Items in one query, and then fetching all the owners in a seperate query each (unless a owner is the same in multiple items, then its returned from the hibernate cache).

So my thought was that graphql-java recursively scans the objects that is returned to it, which causes the hibernate proxies to fetch.

Can i be right about this, or do you think my issue is completely unrelated to graphql-java?

**UPDATE:**

I found out that this has nothing to do with graphql, and is caused by hibernate. My relations are setup as LAZY, but Hibernate ignores this, and makes a query for each Person. So first a query that gets all Item's and next a query for each Person (n+1). And i do not access the proxies myself.

I create the query like this (this is kotlin):

```
entityManager
            .createQuery("SELECT i FROM Item i", Item::class.java)
            .setMaxResults(1000)
            .resultList
```

Answer (score 2):

To make things clear, this has nothing to do with GraphQL.

Hibernate eagerly loads one-to-one relationships by default.

To change this behaviour annotate the person field with

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: I am already using FetchType.LAZY. But i think you are right, that this has nothing to do with GraphQL, and is caused by hibernate itself. But if it was eager loading i would expect it to be able to get all "Person" objects in one query. In my case it makes a query for each Person, which is what led me to believe that graphql was scanning the properties, causing the lazy relations to be fetched.

Comment: GraphQL Java will invoke getters only if they are part of the query, this is what the [PropertyDataFetcher](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v10/data-fetching/) does. 
How are you marking the `person` property as LAZY? I feel like the problem might be there.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and that is also what i expected. What led me to believe that it was a graphql problem, was the order of the queries that was executed, but by debugging i could see that the queries were loaded before my resolver returned. I have updated the question with the fetchtype, sorry for leaving that out. However it is a ManyToOne relation